# Linked dropdownlist in JSP

Tags: jsp, linked-list, html-select

I'm working on a cargo tracking system.In this case for address information i need to 3 dropdownlist that first one is city which the names of city will be retrieved from database.Until here there is no problem.But second dropdown town needs to be fill town names in the city which selected in first dropdown.In the same way district dropdown will be linked to town dropdown.I wrote some code for this but this code reloads the form so all dropdowns turns to default value.Here is my code :

```
<%
    DBOperations db = new DBOperations();
    Connection conn = null;

    conn = db.connect();
    ResultSet rs = db
            .runQuery(conn, "Select distinct city from Adress");
%>
<form method="post" action="addBranch.jsp">
    <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="3">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Enter the Parameters</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>CITY :</td>
                <td><select name="city" onChange="a();">
                        <%
                            while (rs.next()) {
                        %>
                        <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(1)%></option>
                        <%
                            }
                        %>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <%
                if (request.getParameter("city") != null)
                    rs = db.runQuery(conn,
                            "Select distinct town from adress where city='"
                                    + request.getParameter("city") + "'");
            %>
            <tr>
                <td>TOWN</td>
                <td><select name="town" onChange="this.form.submit();">
                        <%
                            while (rs.next()) {
                        %>
                        <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(1)%></option>
                        <%
                            }
                        %>
                </select>
            <tr>
```

In this case what should i do?How can i implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your code what the method a(); in JavaScript is doing. Additionally in your TOWN list dropdown, when the onChange happens, you are simply submitting the form which is leading back to the addBranch.jsp page, which I guess reloads the whole thing again.

I suggest that you look at alternate ways of implementing this. The chief reasons being:
1) You are mixing up too much of Script code in the HTML. 
2) You could also optimize the server side implementation in case of similar lookups for towns, etc.

You should look at using Ajax over here and implementing SErver side API calls to retrieve list of towns, list of districts based on town, etc. The Ajax calls should be made when the onChange happens in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Writing scriptlet is not a good idea jsp is meant for presentation logic alone. 
This is wat you should do,
1)Listen for drop down change with jquery/javascript.
2)On change of the drop down make a ajax call to servlet and get the data for next drop down and populate it.

Refer these posts, try it out and d get back if ur stuck with anything in particular.

[How to make a cascading drop down box in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755899/how-to-make-a-cascading-drop-down-box-in-jsp)